# MonoRail Select Using Enum

Tags: castle-monorail

I've been following [this guide](http://www.jamesthigpen.com/blog/2008/07/10/formhelperselect-with-enum/) and coming up with my own concoction in order to use MonoRail's `FormHelper.Select` that is generated from an enum.  So here's the Brail syntax:

```
${FormHelper.Select("user.Role", ${LS.EnumToPairs(Roles)}, {"value":"First", "text":"Second"})}
```

"LS" is just my own helper, which I've defined as follows:

```
public IEnumerable<Pair<int, string>> EnumToPairs(Type e)
{
    IList<Pair<int, string>> pairs = new List<Pair<int, string>>();

    foreach (int val in Enum.GetValues(e))
        pairs.Add(new Pair<int, string>(val, Enum.GetName(e, val)));

    return pairs;
}
```

Yet from this, despite being the correct syntax, I get the following error:

> Node '$({ return Castle.MonoRail.Views.Brail.ExpandDuckTypedExpressions_WorkaroundForDuplicateVirtualMethods.Invoke(self.GetParameter('LS'), 'EnumToPairs', (self.GetParameter('Roles'),)) })' has not been correctly

The source error doesn't help much unfortunately:

> Line 15: output FormHelper.TextField("user.Role", {"class":"text-input full-width"})
>   Line 16: output """
>   Line 17:     """
>   Line 18: output FormHelper.Select("user.Role", ${LS.EnumToPairs(Roles)}, {"value":"First", "text":"Second"})
>   Line 19: output """

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

Based on the answer given below, the solution was finally this:

```
${FormHelper.Select("user.Role", LS.EnumToPairs(Roles), {"value":"First","text":"Second"})}
```

Where Roles was `PropertyBag["Roles"] = typeof(Role);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
${FormHelper.Select("user.Role", LS.EnumToPairs(typeof(Roles)), {"value":"First", "text":"Second"})}
```

Comment: This was very close, but it wouldn't let me do `typeof(Role)` (that's the actual enum type) or `typeof(Roles)` if `Roles` was in the PropertyBag as I had shown in my code.  Instead I did `LS.EnumToPairs(Roles)` where there was `PropertyBag["Roles"] = typeof(Role);` - don't ask me why it wouldn't let me, because Role isn't even in a namespace.  Your idea led to the solution though.

Comment: @Kezzer: right, you'd have to put the full namespace of `Role` and make sure is has the correct assembly reference.

Comment: Indeed, but `Role` was never in a namespace, so I wasn't sure what happens in that circumstance.  I did try `Project.Role` on the import without any luck.  Not sure what went on there really.