# How to populate Castle FormHelper RadioField with an enum property

Tags: .net, data-binding, castle-activerecord, castle-monorail, nvelocity

I am trying to work with enums as properies in my models, as decribed in this [Castle Monorail page](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/recipes/enumprop.html) But I am having some problems when populating a a [radio button](http://www.castleproject.org/monorail/documentation/v20/helpers/form/Generated_FormHelper.html#FormHelper_Methods19) with that property.

I am using this `nvelocity` syntax in my view:

```
$formHelper.RadioField("myModel.MyEnumProperty", 1, "%{}")
```

(being `1` the integer value for the enum, and also the value that my model have)

How it should be done? Plus for an answer that also deals with the biding (which will probably be an issue as well)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [MonoRail Select Using Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519593/monorail-select-using-enum) I did something like this:

```
#foreach($item in EnumToPairs(typeof(MyEnum)))
    $Form.RadioField("myModel.MyEnumProperty", $item.First)
    $Form.LabelFor("myModel.MyEnumProperty", $item.Second)
#end
```

And then on the controller, you would just use ARDataBind or DataBind normally.